# Wordpress: First Article, A Column; Other articles, 2 Columns

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a website (with Wordpress 3.6) and would like to put the news/articles arranged as follows:

-The first article was with the maximum size (one column);

-The following articles were arranged in two columns.

Appears only 5 or 7 articles per page. Someone can help me do this? Please!

Regards,

Comment: Multi post, answered here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115128/first-article-single-column-other-articles-2-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115128/first-article-single-column-other-articles-2-columns

Thanks to all! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the loop that does the following:

queries latest 7 posts

displays first post in first column

the remaining 6 in two divs with the same class, that you can style to form columns

```
<?php
$count = 1; // this is the variable that will count how many posts have been shown
$my_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=7');
if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while($my_query->have_post()) : $my_query->the_post();
    if($count == 1) { // this is the output for the first post
    ?>
    <div id="full-post">
    // post contents
    </div><!-- end .full-post -->

<?php $count++; // here we increment the counter
 } elseif ($count == 2 || $count == 5) { ?>
   <div class="column"> // notice that only on 2nd and 5th iteration we are only opening the column div
        <div class="post-container">
           // post contents
        </div><!-- end .post-container -->
   <?php count++; ?>
 } elseif ($count == 4 || $count == 7) { ?>
    <div class="post-container">
     //post contents
    </div><!-- end post.container -->
    </div><!-- end .column --> // here we are closing the column div
    <?php $count++;
 } else { ?>//these are just normal posts
     <div class="post-container">
     //post contents
    </div><!-- end post.container -->
    <?php $count++;
 }
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Hi! I'm "new" on this world! Where I put this?

Comment: I have added it to index.php and say it: " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in E:\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Ourique\index.php on line 25" ... Can You Explain ir better for me?

Comment: i missed few closing tags, that s why you where getting this error. i've edited the code so you can use it. and yes, place it in your index file where posts should show up.